# How do I remove Angular from my references in an ASP.NET 5 app?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Being the absolute noob to ASP.NET 5 (and MVC6), today I tried installing Angular using nuget, i.e. `Install-Package AngularJS.Core`. I was expecting it to appear under the `Scripts` folder I created. I didn't know it was already a bower package. Now my two References folders have references marked with a warning triangle for Angular. How do I get rid of these?

When I try `Uninstall-Package AngularJS.Core`, I get an error message,

> Package 'AngularJS.Core' to be uninstalled could not be found in
>   project 'Qsaas.Ui'

Yet the troublesome references still exist.

Comment: Do you have "AngularJS.Core" on your __project.json__ file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET 5 uses NuGet only for **server-side** components. If your server don't use JavaScript directly (like Node.js do for example) then you have to swich to usage of [bower](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/bower.html) or alternatively [npm](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-grunt.html#configuring-npm). [The part](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/angular.html) of documentation describes how one can include AngularJS in ASP.NET 5 project.

To remove NuGet package which you installed by `Install-Package AngularJS.Core` you can use `Uninstall-Package AngularJS.Core`. By the way, if you new in ASP.NET 5, I recommend you to examine `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages` and `%userprofile%\Oleg\.dnx\packages` where you will find the installed packages. See [the article](http://blog.nuget.org/20151008/NuGet-3-What-and-Why.html#global-packages-folder) for details.

**UPDATED:** After executing of `Install-Package AngularJS.Core` command, the folder `AngularJS.Core` will be created in the user profile under both `%userprofile%\.dnx\packages\AngularJS.Core` and `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\AngularJS.Core`. You will see additionally `AngularJS.Core (1.4.7)` as folder under `References\DNX 4.5.1` and `References\DNX Core 5.0` of your project. The only real changes in your project will be including the line `"AngularJS.Core": "1.4.7"` in `"dependencies"` section of `project.json` file. If you just remove the line `"AngularJS.Core": "1.4.7"` from the `project.json` file you will see "Rest" immediately after you save the changes in the `project.json` file. You can verify that `AngularJS.Core` will stay in both `%userprofile%\.dnx\packages` and `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`. You can just remove the folders if you don't nees the package in other your projects.

Now you can add new item to the project in context menu of Visual Studio. You can choose "Client-Side\Bower Configuration File". It will create `bower.json` file in your project. Then you can include `"angular": "~1.4"` for example in `"dependencies"` part of `bower.json` (the name of angular in bower repository if `angular`). After you save the sile you will see "Restoring packages..." message and you will see the package in `Dependencies` of the project

[image]

You will see Angular files under `wwwroot\lib\angular` of your project. If you would click on "Show All Files" you will see `.bowerrc` file as the child of `bower.json`. If have the following content:

```json
{
    "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

You can consider to use another location of bower libraries on your web. You can just follow the steps descrined in [the article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ControlHowYourBowerPackagesAreInstalledWithAGulpfileInASPNET5.aspx).

Comment: Please see my edits about trying to uninstall the package.

Comment: @ProfK: I posted more detailed instructions in **UPDATED** part of my answer. I hope it will help you to solve the problem.

Comment: I found simply deleting it from project enough. It already was a bower package I hadn't see

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your error message is that Visual Studio want to remove the project `AngularJS.Core` from `project.json` but the line referencing it isn't in `project.json`. I'd imagine it's either another package with a different name and that it resides in the `bower.json` by looking at the screenshot you provided.

Nuget Package Manager and the Command Console simply create entries in either your `project.json` or your `bower.json`

You can also manually delete the entries from those files and it will delete it from your project as soon as you have saved the file.

e.g.in your `project.json` remove the `AngularJS.Core` row entry e.g.

```
"dependencies": {
   "AngularJS.Core": "1.4.7",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta8",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta8",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta8",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8",
 }
```

to

```
"dependencies": {
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta8",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta8",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta8",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8",
 }
```

If I were you I would remove any lines referencing angular in both the `project.json` and `bower.json` and save the files. Visual Studio will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open Manage NuGet Packages again on your project and click on the Installed Packages, from there you will see the option to Unistall

[image]

Comment: Please see my edits about trying to uninstall the package.